# How to display multiple fields in one line in drupal

Tags: 7, entities, hooks

First of all I'm new to Drupal. I want to add 3 form fields inline as shown in the image. So I want to know what is the best method of doing it.

[image]

Comment: u need to make some css

Comment: Use firebug and find the id of each and create css for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to use CSS to achieve this. Drupal makes it really easy by wrapping the elements nicely with divs and relevant classes. For example, if you are creating a new issue in [Drupal.org](http://drupal.org), the form provides http://drupal.org/project/issues/linkedin?categories=All this kind of structure.

Using an inspector tool, you can find the target divs and apply a CSS in this way to your theme:

```
.views-exposed-form .views-exposed-widget {
    float: left;
    padding: 0.5em 1em 0 0;
}
```

Thats it. Don't forget to clear your cache to see the changes!